# Google Maps API and Lua

Tags: google-maps, lua

I am a developer working on Lua scripting as my backend code for mobile app development. I have a requirement to use the Google Maps service and the google directions service within my Lua script to enable GPS tracking and sore some of the information into a database.

The following link helped me a little to understand how to achieve the functionality but is the same possible with Lua Script? (where I don't use any HTML or javascript anywhere).

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Comment: If you are working on a Lua backend, what frontend are you using? If you wish to serve information to users, I guess you will be using HTML+JavaScript. Google maps (at least the API you refer to) runs on client side in the browser, not on the server side.